# Flutter Container inside the GridView

Tags: flutter

My code adds text to the first screen from a `GridView.` I have this `GridView`, which returns a container that resizes from `Text`, but the containers are very separate.

How do I join them?

```
Expanded(
         child: GridView.builder(
         padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
         itemCount: contacts.length,
         gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
         ),
         itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return GestureDetector(child: Align(child: ClipRRect(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
               clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
               child: Container(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                   constraints: BoxConstraints(
                       maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
                   ),
                   color: Colors.grey[900],
                   child: Padding(
                       padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                       right: 15, left: 15, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                       child: Text(contacts[index].texto ?? '',
                           maxLines: 2,
                           overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                           style: TextStyle(
                               color: Colors.white,
                               height: 2.5,
                               letterSpacing: 1,
                ))))),
            ),onTap:(){_showContactPage(contact: contacts[index]);});
      },
))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your container to take all the available size just specify the width and height as double.infinity
Hope this helps.

Comment: It still remains separate even if I change or remove padding and the ross spacing and main spacing.It has the height and width of the size that Text sends but the containers are very separate I want to know how to put them together without having to increase their height

Answer (score 0):

because you set cross spacing and main spacing to 5.0 just change the values.

Comment: You have a lot of paddings: padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),

Comment: It still remains separate even if I change or remove padding and the ross spacing and main spacing.It has the height and width of the size that Text sends but the containers are very separate I want to know how to put them together without having to increase their height

Comment: remove max height of container

Comment: Mas não quero que ele aumente, eu quero que ele aproxime do outro container, sem ter que aumentar a altura dele se eu fizer isso muda o design